# Android Card Reader HID input

Tags: android, io, usb, hid

I need to be able to communicate with the Magtek Mini over HID.

Android can communicate when the Magtek is set to keyboard emulation but than every 5 or so swipes android drops some characters. This is not good when reading in credit cards. If possible some example code would be great. Thanks.

Comment: Did you try making a c application with the http://www.signal11.us/oss/hidapi/ first?